# Permission denied for whereis, javac, javadoc when executing shell commands from android app

Tags: android

I was learning that how one can execute shell commands via Android app, but got stuck with some of the commands as Android is denying permission by stating

```
Cannot run program "whereis": error=13, Permission denied
```

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;
    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // runtime permission to read external storage is already provided

        textView = findViewById(R.id.tv);
        executeShellCommand();
    }


    private void executeShellCommand() {
        try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("whereis calculator"); // not working
            // Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("whereis java"); // not working
            // Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ls /Internal storage"); // working 
            // Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("which ls"); // working on android
            // Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -n 1 -d 1"); // working                   
            // Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javadoc storage/emulated/0/java/lang/String.java"); // not working
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

            try {
                proc.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "IO Exception " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            while (read.ready()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String s = read.readLine();
                Log.i("log i in while loop", s);

                textView.append(s + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("IOE...........", "IOE catch: " + e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(this, "IO Exception " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I have several queries regarding this

1. How to run some of the commands like whereis, javac via android app
2. How to list files(using `ls`) and permissions(using `ls -l`) of Internal Storage directories(like Documents, Downloads, Pictures, DCIM etc)via app
3. How to generate document for a Class/Interface using javadoc using shell command
4. Which among the 2 will be good practice to generate document for a class/Interface 
   a. either inside phone memory
   b. or in inside the app itself
   to access them as per the requirement.

I will be grateful if someone can help me regarding these queries. Thank you.

Comment: "How to run some of the commands like whereis, javac via android app" -- there is no guarantee of any particular programs existing on any given Android phone, such as the `ls`, `which`, and `top` that you say are "working". In particular, it is unlikely that `javac` exists on any Android phone. So, your first step would be to determine where you will get `javac` from that runs on Android, and how that `javac` will get onto a phone of interest to you.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for suggestion, I really appreciate it. Can you please tell me how to list files and their permissions (using `ls -l`) of my Internal phone storage like Pictures, Bluetooth, Download, Documents, DCIM(All are directories of internal phone storage) as `ls` is working via android.

Comment: I would not expect that to work well. Android's file permission system does not map to *nix-style permission values, and your app does not have access to everything anyway.

Comment: @CommonsWare Got it. Thank you.